# Count of distinct in MySql

Tags: mysql, join, count, distinct

I want to take count of distinct value in mysql.

```
select 
    bank_sample_map.sample_track_id,sample_details.sample_id,order_number, order_details.sample_detail_id 
from 
    bank_sample_map 
left join 
    sample_details on bank_sample_map.sample_track_id = sample_details.sampletrack_id 
left join 
    order_details on order_details.sample_detail_id = sample_details.sample_id 
where 
    sample_detail_id = 559662
```

It returns

[image]

While Querying with distinct, It returns 2 rows

```
select 
    DISTINCT(bank_sample_map.sample_track_id),sample_details.sample_id,order_number, order_details.sample_detail_id 
from 
    bank_sample_map 
left join 
    sample_details on bank_sample_map.sample_track_id = sample_details.sampletrack_id 
left join 
    order_details on order_details.sample_detail_id = sample_details.sample_id 
where 
    sample_detail_id = 559662
```

And while I am trying to take count, it returns 6. But I need the count 2.

Comment: How are you taking the count?

Answer (score 1):

I found a Query And it returns 2.

```
select 
    count(distinct(order_number)),bank_sample_map.sample_track_id,sample_details.sample_id, order_details.sample_detail_id 
from 
    bank_sample_map 
left join 
    sample_details on bank_sample_map.sample_track_id = sample_details.sampletrack_id 
left join 
    order_details on order_details.sample_detail_id = sample_details.sample_id 
where 
    sample_detail_id = 559662
```

Answer (score 0):

run your query as the second example, then use the built in count function to see how many rows you have.

mysqli:

```
  if ($result = $mysqli->(" query in here")) {
    /* determine number of rows result set */
    $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;
    /* close result set */
    $result->close();
  }
```

[php mysqli num rows documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)

Comment: How do you know he's using PHP?

Comment: very good point; could have sworn I was viewing php questions.